# neither user 10632 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE error in Android 6

Tags: android, permissions, runtime-error, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am developing an Android application in Android 6 and my application in a service needs to get device ID(`getDeviceId`). I have set `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` in the manifest file, but at run time I got this error:

```
neither user 10632 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. java.lang.SecurityException:getDeviceId need android.permission.Read_Phone_state
```

I install my apk file using `adb install myapk.apk` and I suppose that all of application's required permissions are granted at install time.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for user permissions in Android 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091327/how-to-ask-for-user-permissions-in-android-6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neither user 10102 nor current process has android.permission.READ\_PHONE\_STATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742327/neither-user-10102-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-read-phone-state)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to request permission at run time.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

> If the app has the permission, the method returns PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED, and the app can proceed with the operation. If the app does not have the permission, the method returns PERMISSION_DENIED, and the app has to explicitly ask the user for permission.

If you dont get it , you should request it

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
```

Comment: Is there any way that I do not ask user at runtime about permissions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for permissions at runtime in android 6+. Visit android developer page to learn how to ask for permission for android M and above visit : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html